# Variable initialization in vhdl

Tags: initialization, vhdl, synthesis

I am using Xilinx Isim for vhdl simulation. i have intialized a variable like `(signal q: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):="0000000000000000";)`. But when it comes to simulation that particular value is not initialized. its showing `undefined('U')`. I have to use that value in feedback. so the values depending on it are also `undefined('U')`. And one more thing, if initialize the signal is get synthesized? what happens when I dump it in to an FPGA? please tell me the solution

Comment: This was a rather poorly formatted question, and is difficult to understand. The sentence `"And one more thing, if initialize the signal is get synthesized?"` is particularly confusing. Please consider re-writing and re-formatting a bit so we can better help you.

Comment: Please provide a VETSMOD code example: a very short, but valid piece of VHDL that we can run on our compiler to try and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The initialisation expression will work in ISIM, as well as for synthesis with XST. What you are seeing suggests there is a driver on that signal which is uninitialised or not properly reset. Find and check all the drivers on that signal - reading the ISIM documentation for its "drivers" command may help you in this task.